# Alternative/Remap `fn` key in OSX Terminal.app for `tmux`

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, tmux, terminal.app

I use `tmux` within macOS Sierra `Terminal.app`. When I want to disable Allow mouse reporting temporarily to copy/paste and clicking I need to press the `fn` key which is far away in my long apple keyboard. Is there a way to change this fn key to a closer key like `ctrl, alt, option`? I could not seem to find how after googling for a while.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you disabling mouse reporting (Cmd-r for me) to copy and paste? Tmux has copy paste buffers, and macOS has pbcopy/pbpaste commands. This has nothing to do with vim, through from vim the `*` register should work, or you can write lines to `!pbcopy` and read lines from `!pbpaste`

Comment: when you are in tmux with mouse reporting you use tmux mouse selection but you cannot copy with cmd+c for instance (it is visual selection i think). if you hold fn key while mouse select then you are able to cmd + c. thats my point here.

Comment: Tmux uses `prefix-[` and `prefix-]` for copy and paste. No you cant use cmd-c, but you can feed the copied text to vim or to `pbcopy` (which is the same as using cmd-c). And you can hit cmd-r ro disable mouse if you absolutely must. Ill try to write up an answer describing my workflow when i get time.

Answer (score 6):

To toggle mouse reporting, press <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> in Terminal.app.

---

I would like to share my Terminal.app + tmux + vim workflow as it relates to copy-paste, to suggest an alternative.

## Vim to system

With vim from homebrew or `+clipboard` support, I make use of the `"*` register for yanks and puts. This interfaces well with the rest of the system.

You can always `:r !pbpaste` or `:w !pbcopy` too (described below).

## Shell to system

macOS provides `pbcopy(1)` and `pbpaste(1)`. By default they use the system clipboard. `pbcopy` is a sink that reads from stdin, while `pbpaste` is source that writes to stdout.

I use these regularly for command-line clipboard interactivity.

## Tmux copy & paste

Enter copy-mode with the tmux `copy-mode` command (<kbd>Prefix</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd> by default).

Navigate with a series of keybindings.

Depending on `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` containing `vi`, tmux uses `copy-mode` with emacs-style bindings or `copy-mode-vi` with vi-like bindings—you can change the default in your `.tmux.conf` with the `status-keys` and `mode-keys` options. See `man tmux` for more details.

The default vi-like bindings are a bit lacking, in my opinion, so I opted to put the following in my `.tmux.conf`:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi v send-keys -X begin-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-selection-and-cancel
```

Once I've made a selection, I can put it anywhere in tmux with <kbd>Prefix</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd>. There are buffers to choose from as well.

### Tmux & vim

I can paste in vim via `:set paste`, `o`, and my tmux paste key. I use unimpaired, so paste toggling becomes `]op`. With Tim Pope's tbone from github, I can also use `:Tput` and `:Tyank` in vim.

### Tmux and system

**Update**: I've recently learned that the following will do the trick!

```
tmux show-buffer | pbcopy
```

This is the hardest piece: I usually do the following at a shell:

```
# pbcopy <<<'{TMUX PASTE}'
```

It's not perfect: if I paste anything with single quotes, I usually have to go through and do some editing work. In bash with readline in vi-mode, this as simple as `<Esc>kv` and then I can edit in vim until I'm satisfied.

A simpler and less error-prone alternative is often

```
# pbcopy
{TMUX PASTE}
<C-d> # send End-of-file
```